# How to find smallest and largest "cells" on these images?

Tags: python, algorithm, computer-vision

I have the task to first find all "cells" on images using Python, then count them and last but not least find the smallest and largest of these cells/areas. On such image could look like this:

[image: Sample image]

The bright areas are the "cells" to identify, the black lines and areas are gaps in between. I was trying to find a solution to this problem with OpenCV's `findContours()` function, but I wasn't able to correctly find *all* lines between those cells, e.g. the very thin one in the lower left corner. Moreover, how could I filter out only the bright cells with this approach and ignore the black gaps in between?

Comment: looks like cracks in concrete/rock. there have been similar questions before, using those terms. -- those bright blocks are the objects. you do not use findContours to find the gaps, you use it to find the blocks. **do not use canny**, it's a noob trap. -- when those fragments touch, it's near impossible to separate them using simple image processing. you'd need AI and even that isn't guaranteed to work well, but it probably will.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Thanks for your response. I was thinking of AI (CNNs?) as well, but haven't found a similiar use case. Could you please be so kind and elaborate on this?

Comment: segmentation, instance segmentation specifically. the network would learn to take hints from clearly visible parts of a crack "line" and extrapolate into the hard to see pieces of a line. here the lines are straight-ish so I'd expect a network to learn this easily. however you'll need some labeling. this might be amenable to data augmentation or entirely synthetic data, where you (your algorithm) determine where cracks are and how their thickness varies. real data (labeled) is more valuable though. you could start by drawing along the cracks, then giving each block its own label.

Comment: Approach #1: Load image, grayscale, Gaussian Blur, Otsu's threshold, Morph open with elliptical shaped kernel. Now we do two pass contour filtering. 1st pass: find contours, filter using contour area and effectively remove all tiny noise contours and fill them in with `cv2.drawContours`. Now we only have cell contours left. 2nd pass: find contours and sort using contour area. That should give you the smallest/largest contours. You can also throw in a counter for the number of cells.